# Understanding frequency in time-series object R (spectral analysis)

Tags: r, time-series, frequency, spectral-density

I am trying to find out whether or not there is a 6-monthly seasonality in my data. I want to do it with spectral analysis, where I would look at the Ftest of the spectrum at a specific frequency.

I am looking for help to understand what the x-axis in the spectral analysis means (i.e. what the frequencies mean) if I calculate it based on a time-series object with frequency 12.

Here some data generated. My data is collected every month over 10 years:

```
data = ts(1:120, frequency = 12, start = c(1959, 1)) # data that is collected each month over 10 years.
library(multitaper)
resSpec <- spec.mtm(data, nFFT = "default", 
                Ftest = TRUE,
                jackknife = FALSE, maxAdaptiveIterations = 100,
                plot = TRUE, na.action = na.fail)
```

[Output from multitaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niByN.png)

If I am looking for the spectral power at a 6 month (2 times per year) cycle, am I looking for frequency 1/6 or 6/12?

Answer (score 0):

The frequency output is cycles per year, not month.  You can check this as such:

```
curve <- function(i) {
    sin(2*pi/6 * i)
}

data = ts(sapply(1:120, curve), frequency = 12, start = c(1959, 1))

resSpec <- spec.mtm(data, nFFT = "default", 
                Ftest = TRUE,
                jackknife = FALSE, maxAdaptiveIterations = 100,
                plot = TRUE, na.action = na.fail, dtUnits="year", deltat=1/12)
```

So the frequency you're looking for is 2 (cycles/year)

Comment: Thank you very much! That is very helpful.